# Detecting the use of private APIs

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, debugging

I'm being rejected on the App Store for using private instance variables in my app. The ivars I am supposedly using are most definitely not being accessed in my code, but I am using one or two static libs from third parties. How would I test whether these could actually be the offenders?

**Update:**

Apple is accusing me (and 3rd party libs) of using private instance variables in the UITouch class, including

- _locationInWindow
- _tapCount
- _previousLocationInWindow
- _timestamp
- _touchFlags
- _phase
- _window

Comment: How about replacing the third party libs by not offending stubs and test if it fails?

Comment: I don't want to have to go through 2 review cycles if I can get it done in one

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't know anything about detecting the problem, but we encountered this problem recently; in our case it was caused by the Three20 library. If you are using it, see http://groups.google.com/group/three20/browse_thread/thread/c442af6e39a918b0/2375e7a158ee9d1b for a discussion/possible solutions.

Comment: I am indeed using Three20, looks like this will solve my issue. Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 5):

You can use `nm` to scan for which library uses the `ivar` in question.

```
% nm static_lib.a | grep name_of_ivar
```

If you get a line, I think with a capital `U`, with the name of the `ivar` you probably have a suspect.

Comment: Exactly the stuff I'm looking for, will give it a bash. Thanks

Comment: OK so I ran nm -a static_lib.a and it does not look like it's showing any message calls to the UIKit classes, it only shows something like this: U .objc_class_name_NSCharacterSet

Comment: I read your update. Those vars can be accessed in a straight struct way, making them being offsets known by the compilers...so I think you should focus on which parts uses UITouch stuff. ie, who uses/defines touchesBegin:/touchesMove:/touchesEnd:

Answer (score 1):

> I am using one or two static libs
>   from third parties

Contact the third parties, requesting explanation, they wrote the code, they must know what's in there. They might have a forum or a comments section, where other users might have expressed these concerns already, and you can look for answers and alternatives.

Comment: I've done both, the vendor denies using the private APIs and I haven't found any similar complaints, but I'd still like to know for sure

Answer (score 0):

For those who have many third-party libraries, can check your project in such a manner in your project path, for example if you want to find `GraphicsService`:

```
$ find . |grep "\\.a" | xargs grep GraphicsService
```