# JSON framework w/o hidden APIs?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode

Given all the issues around hidden APIs and Apple now checking for them before releasing anything into the app store, how can you be sure if a particular framework is using hidden APIs?  For example, I like the Google JSON framework: http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/.  I have no idea if they are using hidden APIs.

What else is there for JSON that you can be sure isn't using hidden APIs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can audit the code.

1. First make sure the project compiles without warnings. That means that all the methods they use have to be declared in their headers.
2. Then look at all the categories declared in the code (you can do this yourself, or find some tool to do that).
3. For all categories declared on classes provided by all Apple frameworks, make sure there are concrete implementations of the methods they declare in your code. If there are any categories on Apple provided classes that do not have concrete implementations provided by the framework then they are declaring the category in order to avoid compile warnings accessing private methods.
4. Look for calls to NSClassFromString, and make sure all uses of it are for public classes

There are some other ways they could be using private APIs, but they are not as common and tend to be caused by people actively trying to obfuscate what they are doing.

A little more on point:

I have audited [YAJL-objc](http://github.com/gabriel/yajl-objc) myself, and I am sure that Jon is doing nothing bad in [TouchJSON](http://code.google.com/p/touchcode/wiki/TouchJSON), because he is damn fine iPhone developer. Beyond that I can't see why any JSON library would be, there is almost nothing they can use hidden in the private APIs. It tends to be more common to use private APIs to achieve visual effects are interface with HW functionality that is not exposed, parsing is really just computational.

Answer (score 1):

There is also [TouchJSON](http://code.google.com/p/touchcode/wiki/TouchJSON). The accepted answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286087/best-json-library-to-use-when-developing-an-iphone-application) question states that is one of the most trust-worthy and well-tested.

As for detecting the use of private API-s, you can take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740588/detecting-the-use-of-private-apis/1740868#1740868) question for a couple of possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

See all the libraries listed at [json.org](http://json.org/).

Comment: "All" of them except the two mentioned thus far in this post?!?

Comment: "See all" doesn't mean that site lists all the ones that have ever been written.

Answer (score 0):

Look for projects to start adding descriptive text verifying they use no private API's nor do they plan to.

It is an interesting issue though, as Three20 is not the first library this has happened to.  Nothing beats a quick review of the code on your own.

Answer (score 0):

I do agree there are a lot of solution to JSon parsing, but writing your own solution is quite simple.

it mainly depends on how complicated json sources are.
typical C/c++ impelmentations tend to be a lot mor efficient, and in regard to your question about private API's. as long as You copy/ past sources, you are sure you are not using private apis.