# Detecting private API's in my application - Beginner

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I use to download and install various libraries from the internet. Now i am not sure if those libraries use **private API's**.

1. How do i know if a library that i downloaded uses private API's (which Apple **dislikes**)
2. There are 3rd party software's that could detect these libraries. Can someone give me a free 3rd party software where i could use to scan my application.
3. Has anyone come across an article/blog/discussion where Apple have listed all reasons where an app could get rejected

Comment: Ask the author. Few libraries use private APIs.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detecting the use of private APIs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740588/detecting-the-use-of-private-apis)

Comment: The most common way of knowing is usually a yellow warning about an undefined variable. (case in point, the CAFilter Class).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

App scanner by Chipmunk Studios is able to scan for private API usage in .app files, show and search method signatures, provide documentation to peruse about private frameworks, AND comes with a sample.  Now if that ain't the answer, nothing is.

http://www.chimpstudios.com/appscanner/