# app rejected due to use of non public (private) api?

Tags: iphone, app-store

How can I know private APIs are used in my App ? 
When I am trying to upload my App to the App Store, they are showing me this kind of Error :

[image]

Can anyone help me out ?

Comment: Maybe you can start by giving us APIs which are used in your app.

Comment: @Shawn How can I know private APIs in my app ?

Comment: Please follow following thread

[iOS otool to detect private apis \[closed\]][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15074043/ios-otool-to-detect-private-apis

Comment: @ajeet you know what APIs you've added to your project, if the list is not too long please give us it. Vin's answer is probably the good one, UDID is not accessible anymore, so the problem is probably here.

Comment: Please go through the below article. http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.in/2010/05/validate-build-product.html **Validate Built Product** is under the *Build Options* in ***Build Settings***

Comment: @Vin : Yes I resolve this issue. and thnx

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the app store and app submission issues, which have been determined to be off topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: For me the cause of above errors was BugSense integration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apple recently disallowed developers from accessing the device's **UDID (Unique Device Identifier)**, but some **Third Party Libraries** haven't updated yet.

If you are using **Google Analytics** in your App, it may be responsible for creating this kind of problems.

There are some other Issues also :

1. [App rejected, but I don't use UDID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16409966/app-rejected-but-i-dont-use-udid).
2. [How does Apple know you are using private API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2842357/how-does-apple-know-you-are-using-private-api)

If you don't use any **private API** then you have a *Method* in your code which has the same name as a **private API**. Go and change that name and re-submit your App.