# How to find out the private API in my Xcode project?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, iphone-privateapi

How can identify the private API(Apple Banned API or code). Because I have to validated the app, but not validated. I am getting the error alert(check screenshot). I removed all the "uniqueIdentifier" code. But still not validate the app. In my app having lot of external resources, so that I am not able to identify the correct private API. Please let me know any suggestion for this problem.

[image]

Comment: Take a look at : http://stackoverflow.com/a/17165725/1603072

Comment: Is this two files are banned "libSignatureToken.a", "libXChangeA.a"? In my app using these two files.

Answer (score 1):

In your case the message indicated that UDID was being accessed.  You can do a search for your entire project for:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier];
```

If your project also included third party static library such as Admob for example, in that case you should get an update from them.  Because accessing to UDID has not been allowed since May 1st.

Comment: Yes. I know very well. I removed all the "uniqueIdentifier" codes.  But in the app having lot of external resources and ".a" files. So that I need How to find out private API's.

Comment: Let me know, Is this two files are banned "libSignatureToken.a", "libXChangeA.a"? In my app using these two files.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got the answer for check the "uniqueIdentifier" in the ".a" file. Please check the screenshot.

If you want to check the "uniqueIdentifier" code on the ".a" file. Use this command.

**find . | grep -v .svn | grep ".a" | grep -v ".app" | xargs grep uniqueIdentifier**

[image]