# Detecting private APIs in iOS application through command line utilities

Tags: ios, ipa, iphone-privateapi

I have used commands like **otool,nm and strings** on my application's binary file but am unable to infer if my method names are actually clashing with Apple's internal APIs ?

Also, have download class-dump and ran it on my .app/AppName file which gives output as

> "This file does not contain any Objective-C runtime information."

Can anyone suggest the way to do it ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detecting the use of private APIs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740588/detecting-the-use-of-private-apis)